# NLog: Logs in wrong file on reload

Tags: c#, nlog

We have a config file that is edited by our GUI to dynamically change the log level of our file target.

Our filename looks like this: fileName="${logDir}${var:subLogDir}/${var:regionName}${logName}.dlog"
All of the variables are in the base .config file of the program and the regionName is set dynamically when the program starts by setting
variable directly in the configuration via NLog.LogManager.Configuration.Variables["regionName"] = string.Concat(RegionName, "/");.

Our problem is when we modify the log level while the program is generating logs, there will be a moment where the logs will fall into the ${var:subLogDir} directly as if the ${var:regionName} is not set even if we know it is.

It seems like there is a moment in time where the dynamic variables are not resolved yet. Is there something we can do to prevent this? Buffering the logs while reloading?

NLog version: 4.7.4

.config file

```
<nlog keepVariablesOnReload="true">
    <variable name="subLogDir" value="/Regions" />
    <include file="..\Common\Logs\BaseVariables.xml" />
    <include file="..\Common\Logs\BaseTargets.xml" />
    <include file="..\Common\Logs\BaseRules.xml" />
</nlog>
```

BaseVariables.xml

```
<nlog>  
  <!-- Default variables values -->
  <variable name="logLevel" value="LogLevel.Info"/>
  <variable name="callstackLogLevel" value="LogLevel.Debug"/>
  <variable name="keepFileOpen" value="true"/>
  <variable name="autoFlush" value="true"/>
  <variable name="concurrentWrites" value="false"/>
  <variable name="hasAudit" value="false"/>
  <variable name="archiveAboveSize" value="52428800"/>
  <variable name="maxArchiveDays" value="365"/>
  <variable name="archiveNumbering" value="DateAndSequence"/>
</nlog>
```

BaseTargets.xml

```
<nlog>
  <targets async="true">
    <target Type="File" name="LogFile" createDirs="true" keepFileOpen="${keepFileOpen}" autoFlush="${autoFlush}"
            fileName="${logDir}${var:subLogDir}/${var:regionName}${logName}.dlog"
            concurrentWrites="${concurrentWrites}"
            cleanupFileName="false"
            archiveFileName="${archiveLogDir}${var:subLogDir}/${var:regionName}${archiveLogName}.dlog"
            archiveEvery="${archiveEvery}" archiveAboveSize="${archiveAboveSize}"
            archiveNumbering="${archiveNumbering}" archiveDateFormat="${archiveDateFormat}" maxArchiveDays="${maxArchiveDays}">
      <layout Type="CSVLayout" delimiter="Tab" >
        <column name="date" layout="${longdate}" />
        <column name="level" layout="${uppercase:${level}}" />
        <column name="source,keywords" layout="${logger}" />
        <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
   </targets>
</nlog>
```

Thanks

Comment: Think your example is so complex, that you wil have to create an issue for the NLog-project, and include a sample application that demonstrates the problem. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the NLog Config Variables to behave in two ways:

1. When editing the NLog.config file, then it should discard the existing NLog Config Variables and take those when reloading the updated NLog.config.

   - This requires that you have configured `KeepVariablesOnReload=false` (default)

     - It would be easier if you had included NLog.config in your question. Instead of having to guess.
2. After the reload of the NLog.config then there is one NLog Config Variable (`${var:regionName}`) that you would like to keep.

   - Because you have configured `KeepVariablesOnReload=false` (default) then I guess you have hooked into `LogManager.ConfigurationReloaded`-event and re-assigning it manually.

     - It would be easier if you had included the logic for dynamic assigment of NLog config variable in your question. Instead of having to guess.

The `LogManager.ConfigurationReloaded`-event is called after the reloaded NLog Config has been assigned and initialized. So any logging happening until having dynamically re-assigned the `${var:regionName}` will get empty value. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3954 and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/3952

The current work-around is stop using `LogManager.ConfigurationReloaded`-event and instead just use NLog Global Diagnostic Context (GDC) for the single NLog Config Variable that needs to be restored on every reload. So it becomes `${gdc:regionName}` and you assign it like this (once at startup):

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("regionName", "Europe");
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

Comment: We set the keepVariablesOnReload to true to avoir having to set it every time the config.xml file are reloaded. That is why I am confused on the behavior.

Comment: @cakeby Then I'm also confused how you actually change the other NLog-config-variables :)

Comment: @cakeby Glad my answer could help you to include more details in your question. You are still missing what version of NLog that you are using, and how/when you dynamically update `regionName` config-variable.

Comment: @cakeby Think your example is so complex, that you wil have to create an issue for the NLog-project, and include a sample application that demonstrates the problem. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new/choose

Comment: Using the GDC fixed our problem anyway. Thanks.